# C programming - use #define to define constant parameters and do operations

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Cpl 830
#define Tl 1708
#define Td 2200  
#define den 7200

int main()
{
    double hd1 = Cpl*(Td - Tl);
    double hd2 = Cpl*(Td - Tl)*den;
    double hd3 = hd1 * den;

    printf("%e\n", hd1);
    printf("%e\n", hd2);
    printf("%e\n", hd3);
    
    return 0; 
}
```

hd2 and hd3 not equal?
the format for asking a question is much harder than the question itself.
these words are existed because it needs to more words to make the question look good.

Comment: Still not enough words "to make the question look good".

Comment: You're getting integer overflow. Enable full compiler warnings.

Comment: `testmacro.c:11:31: warning: overflow in expression; result is -1354775296 with type 'int' [-Winteger-overflow]
    double hd2 = Cpl*(Td - Tl)*den;`

Comment: Compiler say *warning C4307: '*': signed integral constant overflow*.

Comment: Make your constants `long` or `double`. Or cast one of them to `double` in the calculation.

Comment: See what happens if you make your constants `float`s (putting a `.0` on the end of each).

Comment: for example `#define Cpl 830.0` etc.

Comment: @Xuesong Gao,  "hd2 and hd3 not equal?" --> the biggest mistake here is not enabling all compiler warnings.  Save time.  Enable them all.

Comment: @ScottHunter — note that writing `830.0` makes the constants into `double` values.  A `float` value would be `830.0F`; a `long double` value would be `830.0L`.  See C11 [§6.4.4.2 Floating constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.2) for the details.

Comment: It would be sensible to include the output you are getting in the question — with an explanation of the result you expected to see.  This is also a part of creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
double hd2 = Cpl*(Td - Tl)*den;
```

does an integer calculation because all operands are integer constants and converts the result to `double` while the line

```
double hd3 = hd1 * den;
```

does a floating point (double) calculation because one operand is a variable of type `double`.

Add a decimal point to your numbers to mark them as `double` constants.

Also note that `Cpl*(Td - Tl)*den;` is very likely causing *signed integer overflow* with *undefined behavior* as a result.

Comment: so for hd2 = Cpl*(Td-Tl)*den; first do the integer calculation and get a integer; but that integer is too large and fail. understood now.

Answer (score 4):

The statement

```
double hd2 = Cpl*(Td - Tl)*den;
```

is equivalent to:

```
double hd2 = 830 * (2200-1708) * 7200;
```

The type of all the operands of the `*` and `-` operations is `int`, because that is the default type of an [integer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant). This means that also the result of the operations is always of type `int`. However, on your platform, the type `int` is probably not able to represent the mathematical result `2,940,192,000`, because the maximum value representable by an `int` (which is [`INT_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)) is probably `32,767` or `2,147,483,647`, depending on which platform you are using. Therefore, you have a [signed integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), which invokes undefined behavior. On most platforms, this will cause the result value to be truncated.

The data type `double` is able to represent a much greater range of numbers. Therefore, if you change the type of the operands to `double`, the problem will disappear. The easiest way to change the data types to `double` is to add a `.0` at the end:

```
#define Cpl 830.0
#define Tl 1708.0
#define Td 2200.0
#define den 7200.0
```